# Documents Not Appearing in Search Results

Tags: 2010, search, search-results

**SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site Intranet:**

I have a team site with document libraries. For team members, documents are not coming back in search results. Can someone point me in the right direction - I thought this would have worked out of the box?

**UPDATE:**

Search is running regularly as scheduled and actually crawling the sites. This is basically an out-of-the-box scenario, no crawl rules, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a million possible issues on this but here are a few places to start:

- Is Search running regularly and actually crawling sites?  (Search Admin - Crawl log)
- Is Search even crawling the site?  Check the crawl log and verify
  that the documents themselves are being included
- Are there any Crawl Rules defined that might be excluding the
  documents?
- Does the search crawl account have the proper permissions? (Central Admin - Security - Web application user policy)
- Have the default search scopes been modified in some way? (Site Collection Admin - Search Scopes)
- Is the site blocked from search (Site Administration - Search
  visibility)
- Is the Library itself blocked from the search (List Settings -
  Advanced)
- Is the library configured to only allow people to see their own
  items?  (List Settings - advanced)
- Search results are security trimmed so are the documents secured in
  some way that would not allow your team to see them?

Comment: For point 6 & 7, how do I get to Site Admin/Search Visibility and List Settings? Via Site Actions  or Central Admin?

Comment: Site Settings and List Settings, respectively.

Comment: Updating question.

Comment: Turns out that users did not publish docs as major versions!