# Documents do not appear in search results

Tags: search-results

I have a collaborative SharePoint 2010 site, using claim based authentication (FBA and windows). The whole content of the site is successfully indexed (about 5200 objects). When I look into the crawl log, I can see that all stuff (documents, list items,...) are successfully indexed. But when I do a search on my site, documents never appear is search results. But a doc lib view appears in the results. Example: a document titles (Training Session April 2015) won't appear as a document for the search query "Training", but the doc lib view displaying the title of the document will appear in the results. I checked several places, as reported in this post: [Documents Not Appearing in Search Results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63128/documents-not-appearing-in-search-results)

- Is Search running regularly and actually crawling sites? Yes
- Is Search even crawling the site? Check the crawl log and verify that the documents themselves are being included -> Yes
- Are there any Crawl Rules defined that might be excluding the documents? No crawl rule
- Does the search crawl account have the proper permissions? (Central Admin - Security - Web application user policy) -> Yes
- Have the default search scopes been modified in some way? (Site Collection Admin - Search Scopes) -> No, default scope, that includes all content
- Is the site blocked from search (Site Administration - Search visibility) -> no, site configured to be available for search
- Is the Library itself blocked from the search (List Settings - Advanced) -> no, all libs are setup to allow to be searched
- Is the library configured to only allow people to see their own items? (List Settings - advanced) -> no
- Search results are security trimmed so are the documents secured in some way that would not allow your team to see them? -> no special permissions on documents

I also checked whether the fact that some documents are only in draft version (0.1, 0.2) is the problem, but I noticed that published documents also do not appear in results.

Any idea, or a way to investigate further?